# Paypal response slow

Tags: paypal

This is the process flow of a customer buying our service:

1. Create campaign
2. Select a payment method (credit card or paypal). User selects paypal
3. User is redirected to www.paypal.com and makes the payment
4. User is redirected to www.mywebsite.com/dashboard (return_url)
5. User sees his new campaign on the dashboard

When using the sandbox everything is working fine. When using the real service, when the user is redirected to www.mywebsite.com/dashboard, then the new campaign doesn't show up among the records.

I made extensive testing and found that with the live service PayPal gives me the response about 5-10 seconds later than when I am using the sandbox. So when the user is redirected to the his dashboard, the new purchase **is not yet inserted into the database** that's why it doesn't show up! They need to manually hit F5 after a couple of seconds to display the new record.

What can I do about it?

**EDIT**

I managed to bring up this delay problem with the sandbox as well. I found that there is a difference between the demo and the live payment:

In the sandbox, after the payment I see a window with the title **Your payment is complete** saying that I completed the payment, this is the transaction code, and the details will be sent to my email address soon, with two options: Back to the seller account (Back to [sandbox seller account]) and go to the paypal account overview. When I click the first one, it opens another window with the title **Thanks for your order** saying

```
Your payment of $0.99 USD is complete
If you are not redirected within 10 seconds, click here.
```

In the live system after I click Pay Now and the payment is complete, then the first screen does not show up, meaning right after the payment the **Thanks for your order** page is seen then I am redirected to my website (dashboard) within a few seconds.

How could I generate this delay problem in the sandbox?

In the sandbox when the screen shows up about the completed payment when I click quickly the Back to the seller account link, then I click quickly the click here link on the next screen in order to skip the redirection time, the new purchase does not show up on my dashboard on my website, because the data is not yet written into the database.

So the loading of the **Your payment is complete** window in the sandbox plus the time I click the Back to the seller account link is enough for paypal to give me the necessary data and for me to insert it into the database.

I guess the solution could be to activate that first screen in the live system, but how? What do you think?

I thought the solution would be to turn off Auto return but I can't. When I turn it off and click Save, I receive an error *You have not turned on Auto Return. You must turn on Auto Return in order for Payment Data Transfer to work properly*.

Comment: In your live PayPal Account, have you tried setting up Auto Return and Payment Data Transfer? If you need instructions let me know and I can post them.

Comment: Please help me with this. The is returned, it's just slow.

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding Payment Data Transfer and Auto Return to PayPal [Payment Data Transfer Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer).
This is from the official PayPal Documentation:
Payment Data Transfer allows you to receive notification of successful payments as they are made. To use Payment Data Transfer, you need to turn on Auto Return. Here's how:

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click Profile.
3. Click My selling tools.
4. Click Update near "Website preferences".
5. Select On under "Auto Return for Website Payments", and enter your Return URL below.
6. Select On under "Payment Data Transfer".
7. Click Save.

The identity token will then appear in the Website Payment Preferences page of your PayPal account under the "Payment Data Transfer" section. For security purposes, we do not email you the identity token.

You'll need to pass this identity token along with the transaction token to us so you can receive confirmation that the payment is complete.

The slow load can be caused be a number of factors. One of which may be code related. Can you please post some code if you have already enabled Payment Data Transfer, and Auto return?

Comment: I'm looking all of this over. If you have Payment Data Transfer enabled, you have to have Auto Return Enabled. Although Auto Return does not require Payment Data Transfer, Payment Data Transfer requires auto return. If you would like to see if the issue you are experiencing disappears, then you will have to turn off Payment Data Transfer. Try turning both off, and run a transaction to see the results.

Comment: Thank you. Now the live system works the same way the sandbox does. However, I still had to add a `It may take a few seconds to update our databases. Please refresh the page if the new campaign doesn't show up.` with a `dismiss` link to the dashboard in case the user is redirected to his dashboard before the data is written to our database.